# How do I convert this SQL query to LINQ to SQL

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have following SQL query and I want to convert it to LINQ. I want to use a subquery or the LINQ `include` syntax and don't want to use `join`:

```
SELECT Count(*) AS CountOfRecs 
FROM tblAcc a
INNER JOIN tblAccOwner o ON
  a.[Creditor Registry ID] = o.[Registry ID] AND
  a.[Account No] = a.[Account No] 
WHERE 
  (a.[Account Owner ID] = 731752693037116688) AND 
   a.[Account Type] NOT IN ('CA00', 'CA01', 'CA03', 'CA04', 'CA02',
                            'PA00', 'PA01', 'PA02', 'PA03', 'PA04')) AND
  (DATEDIFF(mm, a.[State Change Date], GETDATE()) <= 4 OR
    a.[State Change Date] IS NULL AND 
   (a.[Account Type] IN ('OD','CL00','PL00') OR a.[Account Type] LIKE '%hala%'))
```

Comment: Why don't you send the rest of your project over and we can do that too! How about some effort on your part - What are you trying to achieve? What do your tables look like? What have you tried and whats not working? How about formatting your SQL a bit better...

Comment: Hi Geoff: I am new to Linq. I am trying to get count by I am having a join on two tables. I am an expert in SQL and use LINQ very few times thats why I came on this forum. I didnt meant to post all my project here.

Comment: fair enough, but some of Geoff's points still stand, what did you try, and what about it did not produce the result that you expected? Can you post some of your code?

Comment: hope you don't mind but I've rejigged the query to make it a bit more pleasant on the eyes and have used table aliases instead of table names to reduce visual clutter. I'd also recommend trying to reduce the problem to it's simplest form instead of pasting in a wall of code like that. You're more likely to get help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) or [Linqer](http://sqltolinq.com/). I would try to convert it in LinqPad, but I would have to have the database.

Comment: @dample: I have LinqPad but I dont see option to convert SQL to Linq

Comment: You should get 'translations' of your query (it works like this for linq queries) in sql and lambda.. same behaviour should work in other direction (sql>linq). Even if it won't work as you need, you can still use Linqer, which is actually a SQL to LINQ tool. So I don't understand why I am getting downvotes on this.

Comment: @dample: I used this and When I click the lambda there is no LINQ although Results tab show 1700 count

Comment: @DotnetSparrow: Then try Linqer.

Answer (score 3):

Converting this to Linq should be pretty easy - although I think you should use a `join` if you want the same query!

First create your Linq2Sql model and import your 2 tables, then your query will have the general structure

```
var query = from acc in db.Accs
    join accOwner in db.AccOwners on {acc.regId, acc.AccountNo} equals {accOwner.regId, accOwner.AccountNo}
    where // your where conditions
          // - these should all convert quite easily
          // - just translate them one by one
    select acc;

var count = query.Count();
```

---

If you really need to use subquery then since you are an expert in SQL, then write the query out in SQL first, then test it, then translate the query across to Linq, then test it - taking the translation line by line you'll be fine - and you'll also find Intellisense is wonderful!

---

Please also realise that if you use `.Include()` then you are probably using `join` within the generated SQL anyway.

Comment: In that case I've updated my advice - first use the fact that you are an expert in SQL to translate the query to non-Join format in SQL first.